# RtKit on my ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, passwd, rootkit

Hi I just updated my ubuntu karmic Koala to Lucid Lynx and found sth strange on my file /etc/passwd.

```
rtkit:x:120:130:RealtimeKit,,,:/proc:/bin/false
```

Can someone tell me what it is?

Comment: `apt-cache search RealtimeKit` could have helped you track what it is about...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As the package description says, "Realtime Kit enables realtime scheduling for the PulseAudio daemon". This is an entry for the user running the RealtimeKit daemon.

Comment: ehhh... #WipeSweatFromHead I read "Root Kit"

Comment: Aw, yes. What an unfortunate name, also rtkit-daemon...

Answer (score 5):

It's not actually a required package (only a recommended one):

```
$ aptitude why rtkit
i   pulseaudio Recommends rtkit
```

So you can remove it (though you may find you need if your pulseaudio app doesn't sound so good afterwards - but you can just reinstall it):

```
sudo apt-get remove rtkit
```